# program runs but second function in the program does not print? no error in output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
double a;
double b;
a =(3.0);
b =(5.0);
cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
cout << "------" << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << a*b << "\n" << endl;
system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}

int calculate ()
{
   double a;
   double b;
   double c;
   a = (7.1);
   b = (8.3);
   c = (2.2);
   cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << endl;
   cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "- " << fixed << setprecision (1) << c << "\n" << endl;
   cout << "------" << endl;
   cout << std::setprecision(2) << (a * b) - c << "\n" << std::endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

-Visual Studio doesn't report any errors HOWEVER the second function isn't printed (that is: (a*b)-c)?

Why is this? Do I need to add "int calculate(int a, int b, int c)"?

Comment: `calculate()` does not seem to be called..?

Comment: You are not calling calculate function in the main body?

Comment: You're not calling `calculate` anywhere inside `main`.

Comment: Please don't put parentheses around constant values. `(3.0)` means the same thing as `3.0`, but is harder to read.

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling to function, you need to call it from main with `calculate ()` and have a declaration before usage.

```
//....

int calculate();   //declaration
int main()
{
   //....
   calculate();
}

int calculate()    //implementation
{
   //....
}
```

This is all very basic stuff. I suggest you read an introductory C++ book.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "call it from main". Can I declare it by setting parameters: int calculate (int a, int b, int c)?

Comment: @JustinChiang If you don't know what calling a function means, you probably need to get your hands on a good book.

Comment: oh i understand much better now! thank you for your example!